# Stack a n x n matrix to from a n^2 x 1 column matrix

Tags: matlab

for a 5 x 10 matrix, I wanted to stack the matrix in such a way that each column of the original matrix will be appended to the rows to finally end up with a 50 x 1 matrix.  Basically stack the columns into 1 column.  Thanks.

Here is the start of the matrix:

```
RR = randi(5,5,10);
```

Comment: Either `RR = randi(5, 50, 1);` or, using your code, `RRS = RR(:);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general reshaping operations, use `reshape`, for example:

```
reshape(RR,[],1)
```

This reshapes the array `RR` into an array with an indeterminate number of rows (the `[]`) and 1 column, as you need.

---

Your particular case can use the shortcut mentioned by @beaker in the comments

```
RR(:)
```

This syntax is equivalent to the reshape command above, and simply lists, in one column, all elements of the array.

---

Both of these examples take advantage of the fact that Matlab uses column oriented storage and indexing. If, for some reason, you need to concatenate rows rather than columns, you would need to transpose the `RR` array first. For example:

```
reshape(RR', 1, [])  %This concatenates the rows of RR into a single row. Note the transpose operator.
```